# nodejs UTF-8 encoded string has black question mark

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, utf-8, iconv

I have a csv that I get from my supplier, They have encoded a string with UTF-8 which now includes black question marks. I try to convert it back but am having no luck.

```
var common              = require('./common/index.js');
var fs = require('fs');
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
var encoding  = require('encoding');
var iconv = new Iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
var detectCharacterEncoding = require('detect-character-encoding');
common.fileHandler(
    'default.csv',
    function(dataSet) {
        var fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('file.txt');
        var charsetMatch = detectCharacterEncoding(fileBuffer);
        console.log(charsetMatch);
        console.log(encoding.convert(dataSet[0].description, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1'))
    }
)
```

returns

```
{ encoding: 'UTF-8', confidence: 100 }
<Buffer c3 bd 20 53 79 6e 63 20 64 61 74 61 20 61 6e 64 20 66 61 73 74 20 63 68 61 72 67 69 6e 67 3c 62 72 2f 3e c3 bd 20 50 72 65 6d 69 75 6d 20 61 6c 75 6d 69 ...>
```

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: sometimes when you convert your document once to another encoding format, all original encoding data is gone and you can't do much with this, if you have original version of this csv (not converted yet) then you will have chance to convert it to proper encoding format

Comment: what exactly is `common.fileHandler` doing? what is `dataSet`? you cehck the encoding of `file.txt` but convert `dataSet[0].description` wich seems to be created from `default.csv`? What about all this (different) stuff?

Comment: @neurnet thanks you hit the nail on the head, the actual csv which I recieve from the supplier is encoded with { encoding: 'ISO-8859-1', confidence: 29 }
I've read alot online that this happens between conversion from 'ISO-8859-1' to UTF-8 or vice versa but I cant seem to convert it back or remove the caharacters, Google merchant center (which I import the data back into after validating) is complaining of double UTF8 encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't have original file (before conversion) and you tried everything but with no results you can always replace your question marks with proper utf8 characters :)

just copy question mark and paste it in your code (copy in your editor)

```
someContent.replace('paste_question_mark_here','ą');
```

this is last hope if you loose your encoding data after conversion